# How to redirect the page to another page using Id

Tags: javascript, css, html

For suppose I want to redirect to homepage.php using an ID from the contact page,

here the links are in header.php

like this

`<a href="index.php#my_blog">My Blog</a>`

where it is working in homepage but not in the coantact page

May I know how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

If you go to homepage.php, this should be:

```
<a href="homepage.php#my_blog">My Blog</a>
```

Make sure your ID exists.

Comment: yes, it exists and also working if you click on the homepage, but not on the contact page.

Comment: but the same link is working if i placed in body part instead of in header

Comment: Make sure the ID also exists on the contact page only once and is not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Fo that you have to add `#id` of that particular page to visit it through another page.

```
<a href ="URl#id"> visit</a>
```

For example: you want to got to `contact page` through `contact form id` ie `id=contact-form` from home or any other page of that site then, use like this:

```
<a href ="contact.php#contact-form"> Visit </a>
```